# What does the controller return views as, and what does it do with the model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I render partial views from the controller, are they purely just HTML strings that get appended to a DOM object?

Controller: `return PartialView("~/Areas/Configurations/Views/Supplier/Vouchers/_CardVoucherDetails.cshtml", model);`

Client:`$("#myDiv").html(theReturnedView);`

And when the partial view is returned with a model from the controller, is the model just added as a session or view state and then referenced by the partial view? (because I don't need to handle that at all when rendering the HTML partial view.)

Partial View: `@model Model` Is this just view state?

Comment: There is no such thing as 'view state' in MVC. And yes, a partial view returns html. When you add `@model someModel` and pass `someModel` to the view, it just allows you to access the properties of the model, for example `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.someProperty)` will render the value of `someProperty` as html

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC is stateless which means that there is nothing like View State by default (specific for Web Forms). Partial views (views in general) are transformed by Razor Engine (or aspx Engine, but I guess you use Razor) to the C# classes, which have 'Execute' method where is html content created. Here is interesting article which presents how Razor works: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/17e8f6/razor-engine-working-with-views-in-mvc4758/

Comment: Thanks, that was a good read. Once the partial view is requested from the controller, does the engine generate the class file and immediately execute the method to return the html?

Comment: This is how I understand that.